# Flash p2p: communication between more than 2 clients

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, p2p, adobe-cirrus

I'm doing some experiments with Adobe Cirrus. I've managed to connect 2 clients to each other. But what I want now is the following:
I want client **A** to publish and clients **B** and **C** to play A's stream. I've tried to do this. A starts publishing, B and C create receiving NetStream based on A's nearID. Unfortunately only latest connected to A client can play A's stream. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never used Cirrus, but this other solution seen's to work quite nice. Have a look at it: http://www.flashrealtime.com/local-flash-peer-to-peer-communication-over-lan-without-cirrus/